# Unable to import matplotlib pyplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am unable to import pyplot. How can the error be resolved?

```
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot
Jul 16 12:49:46  Python[35767] <Error>: Set a breakpoint at CGSLogError to catch errors as they are logged.
Jul 16 12:49:46  Python[35767] <Error>: On-demand launch of the Window Server is allowed for root user only.
Jul 16 12:49:46  Python[35767] <Warning>: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (268435459)
Jul 16 12:49:46  Python[35767] <Error>: On-demand launch of the Window Server is allowed for root user only.
Jul 16 12:49:46  Python[35767] <Warning>: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (268435459)
Jul 16 12:49:46  Python[35767] <Error>: This user is not allowed access to the window system right now.
_RegisterApplication(), unable to get application ASN from launchservicesd, and this application requires an ASN, so aborting.  error=#-1.
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the library, it need to be installed first.
It is possible to install it from [official site](https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html).

In Ubuntu it possible to get it via apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

In windows, for standard Python installations, install matplotlib using pip:

```
python -m pip install -U pip setuptools
python -m pip install matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't installed it properly 
You should install it through pip like 
 python  -m pip install -u pip setuptools 
python -m pip install matplotlib

(This method  only works in windows)